# printf not printing after scanf?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    //US CONVERSION RATES
    float const usToGBP = .78;
    float const usToAUD = 1.40;
    float const usToBit = .00027;
    float const usToEur = .88;
    float const usToCAD = 1.33;
    //GBP CONVERSION RATES
    float const gbpToUS = 1.29;
    float const audToUS = .72;
    float const bitToUS = 3696.11;
    float const euroToUS = 1.14;
    float const cadToUS = .75;
//////////////////////////

    float amount;
    printf("How much currency do you have? ");
    scanf("%f", amount);

    //NOTHING BELOW PRINTS
    printf("%f", amount);
    printf("HEYYY");
    printf("||   US   ||   GBP   ||   AUD   ||   BIT   ||   EUR   ||   CAD 
    ||");
```

I'm new to C so I'm still learning syntax of basic input and output. Currently,I'm trying to write a simple program that converts currency. I use `scanf` to take in an amount, however, when I try to print anything after that such as a table or the amount or anything nothing shows up? Can someone please explain why this is occuring?

Comment: Reread whatever taught you how to use `scanf`.

Comment: Enable warnings and read them. `main.cpp:20:11: warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'float*', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]`

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
scanf("%f", &amount);
```

Answer (score 1):

you haven't used the ampersand while taking input

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    //US CONVERSION RATES
    float const usToGBP = .78;
    float const usToAUD = 1.40;
    float const usToBit = .00027;
    float const usToEur = .88;
    float const usToCAD = 1.33;
    //GBP CONVERSION RATES
    float const gbpToUS = 1.29;
    float const audToUS = .72;
    float const bitToUS = 3696.11;
    float const euroToUS = 1.14;
    float const cadToUS = .75;
//////////////////////////

    float amount;
    printf("How much currency do you have? ");
    scanf("%f", &amount); //use ampersand

    //NOTHING BELOW PRINTS
    printf("%f", amount);
    printf("HEYYY");
    printf("||   US   ||   GBP   ||   AUD   ||   BIT   ||   EUR   ||   CAD ||");
}
```